# powershell sql query - fieldlength of 15 - filled just with to chars but my variable gets also length of 15

Tags: sql, powershell

In my powershell script I query a field in a sql database which has a Length of 15 chars. But this is usually filled with only 2 chars. 
I use a Query with a DataSet, the issue is at 'domain'.

```
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        $global:pc = $Row.Item('name')
        $global:pcdomain = $Row.Item('domain')
        $invdate = [string]$Row.Item('InvDate')
    }
```

Hopefully you guys know what I mean.

Is there any way to only get the "real" length of the filled value?

I tried to google, but its hard to find right searchstring for this issue.

Comment: `$Row.Item('domain').Trim()`?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Trim()` method on any string value to remove excess white space characters from the start and end:

```
PS C:\> "    lots of  space   ".Trim()
lots of  space
```

In your case, that would be something like:

```
$trimmedDomainString = $Row.Item('domain').Trim()
```